# Better way to write this "double-barreled list" in Python

Tags: python

The for loop at line 12 and the one nested within it, I mean.  I've encountered situations like this more than once.  I'd use a list comprehension but it doesn't seem like it would work here.

```
import random

import string

def password_generator():
    key = zip(string.digits, string.ascii_uppercase)

    cruft, x = str(random.random()).split('.')

    pw = ''

    for item in x:
        for element in key:
            if item in element:
                Q = random.random()
                if Q > 0.7:
                    pw += element[1].lower()
                else:
                    pw += element[1]

    print pw
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to use a list comprehension:

```
def pw_gen():
    key = zip(string.digits, string.ascii_uppercase)

    cruft, x = str(random.random()).split('.')

    def f(i,e):
      Q = random.random()
      if Q > 0.7:
        return e[1].lower()
      else:
        return e[1]

    return [ f(item,element) for item in x for element in key if item in element ]
```

This returns a list of characters. Use `"".join( pw_gen() )` to convert to a string.

Answer (score 2):

What I think is making it hard for you to do this is that you've got the random.random()<0.7 part in the middle of the loop.  Make that a separate function, and it's easier to turn it into a list comprehension.

```
def f(str):
    if random.random()>0.7:
        return str.lower()
    else:
        return str

''.join([f(element[1]) for element in key for item in x if item in element])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to combine those two, but I get the feeling this task could be simplified using a higher level method from random.

```
symbols=string.ascii_uppercase[:10]
pw = ''
for i in range(15):
  letter = random.choice(symbols)
  if random.random() > 0.7:
    letter = letter.lower()
  pw += letter
```

Or even shorter:

```
symbols = (7*string.ascii_uppercase[:10] +
           3*string.ascii_lowercase[:10])
pw = ''.join(random.choice(symbols) for i in range(15))
```

The way you're building `key` makes it a very inefficient lookup table. You could replace a few lines to use a more efficient method:

```
key = dict(zip(string.digits, string.ascii_uppercase))
#...
for item in x:
    letter = key[item]
```

Admittedly these all produce a fixed length password, and your string conversion had a small chance of getting a shorter number. For similar reasons, though, the last digit was less random than the others.

Comment: This (the `random.choice` example) is pretty much a superior (read: more pythonic) way of doing it.  Part of Python's philosophy is "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it" and this relies heavily on having "batteries included" (and using them!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic can be lot simplified than using a list comprehension to replace the inner for loop. This will be the equivalent of your code:

```
import random
import string
key = dict(zip(string.digits, string.ascii_uppercase))
cruft, x = str(random.random()).split('.', 1)
pw = ''
for item in x:
    if item in key: # This if is not required as all the single digits are present
        Q = random.random()
        if Q>0.7:
            pw += key[item].lower()
        else:
            pw += key[item]
print pw
```

However, I would suggest you to go with [UUID](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) if you really want the password to be unique and not required to reverse engineer easily. If you want a better password generator(with alphanumeric and symbols), you can do something like [this](http://thelivingpearl.com/2013/01/02/generating-and-checking-passwords-in-python/).

Please note that it is not an official python site and also it can be improved in many ways. As usual, it will be your call [to shoot](https://www.python.org/doc/humor/#id4), I mean, to use it in any way.